# Returning to the main activity after exiting a sub activity deactivates two of my buttons

Tags: android

So, I'm working through the big nerd ranch stuff at the moment on Android, and I've wrapped up largely the first application, great fun, whatever, but the problem I'm having is after implementing a cheat button for the quiz, when i return from the cheating screen, my true and false buttons no longer function.

There's definitely a click registered, it just ceases to do anything.

Also having a bug where if I turn it horizontally, the whole app crashes, but I'll post up the code of the two activities and see where we get.

```
    private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue){
        boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isTrueQuestion();

        int messageResId=0;

        if(mIsCheater){
            messageResId=R.string.judgement_toast;
        } else {

            if (userPressedTrue==answerIsTrue) {
            messageResId=R.string.correct_toast;
            } else {
            messageResId=R.string.incorrect_toast;
            }

        Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if(data==null){
            return;
        }
        mIsCheater=data.getBooleanExtra(CheatActivity.EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            mCurrentIndex=savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(Bundle) called");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

        mCheatButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cheat_button);
        mCheatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, CheatActivity.class);
                boolean answerIsTrue=mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isTrueQuestion();
                i.putExtra(CheatActivity.EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answerIsTrue);
                startActivityForResult(i,0);

            }
        });



        mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(true);
            }
        });
        mFalseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(false);
            }
        });


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
        savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);
    }
```

---

```
    package com.example.geoquiz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CheatActivity extends Activity {

    private boolean mAnswerIsTrue;


    public static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE = "com.example.geoquiz.answer_is_true";
    public static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN="com.example.geoquiz.answer_shown";

    private TextView mAnswerTextView;
    private Button mShowAnswer;

    private void setAnswerShownResult(boolean isAnswerShown){
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, isAnswerShown);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cheat);

        mAnswerIsTrue=getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false);

        mAnswerTextView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.answerTextView);
        setAnswerShownResult(false);
        mShowAnswer=(Button)findViewById(R.id.showAnswerButton);
        mShowAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mAnswerIsTrue) {
                    mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.true_button);
                } else {
                    mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.false_button);
                }
                setAnswerShownResult(true);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

On checking the logcat, I've found a null pointer exception regarding the horizontal orientation problem.

```
08-18 18:39:30.398: E/AndroidRuntime(24316): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-18 18:39:30.398: E/AndroidRuntime(24316): Process: com.example.geoquiz, PID: 24316
08-18 18:39:30.398: E/AndroidRuntime(24316): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.geoquiz/com.example.geoquiz.QuizActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-18 18:39:30.398: E/AndroidRuntime(24316):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
08-18 18:39:30.398: E/AndroidRuntime(24316):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
08-18 18:39:30.398: E/AndroidRuntime(24316):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3805)
08-18 18:39:30.398: E/AndroidRuntime(24316):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:139)
08-18 18:39:30.398: E/AndroidRuntime(24316):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1216)
08-18 18:39:30.398: E/AndroidRuntime(24316):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-18 18:39:30.398: E/AndroidRuntime(24316):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-18 18:39:30.398: E/AndroidRuntime(24316):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
08-18 18:39:30.398: E/AndroidRuntime(24316):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 18:39:30.398: E/AndroidRuntime(24316):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-18 18:39:30.398: E/AndroidRuntime(24316):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-18 18:39:30.398: E/AndroidRuntime(24316):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-18 18:39:30.398: E/AndroidRuntime(24316):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-18 18:39:30.398: E/AndroidRuntime(24316): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-18 18:39:30.398: E/AndroidRuntime(24316):    at com.example.geoquiz.QuizActivity.onCreate(QuizActivity.java:116)
08-18 18:39:30.398: E/AndroidRuntime(24316):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
08-18 18:39:30.398: E/AndroidRuntime(24316):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
08-18 18:39:30.398: E/AndroidRuntime(24316):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
08-18 18:39:30.398: E/AndroidRuntime(24316):    ... 12 more
```

Comment: If it crashes, check the logcat. If you don't know what that is, google it. Your life will change. If you find it and still don't understand, post a **relevant** portion here.

Comment: I tried to google around for the buttons not working, but came up empty. The entirety of the code I've given is pretty much all button stuff, which is the issue here. I'm using logcat for the horizontal orientation crash at the moment, I just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: You had a point though, so I've clipped out the next button and previous button bits, and all of the logic that relates to updating the question displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lack of button function was diagnosed using logcat.v and printing the boolean value of mIsCheater in the logcat. After making sure the boolean value prints, and what, at the point of answer checking it is, I rewrote the checkAnswer logic to check what the value actually is - the problem prior to this was that in this code it's just checking if the variable exists it seems.

Anyway, the fixed code is

```
private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue){
boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isTrueQuestion();

    int messageResId=0;

    if(mIsCheater==true){
        messageResId=R.string.judgement_toast;  
    }

        else if (userPressedTrue==answerIsTrue) {
            messageResId=R.string.correct_toast;
    } else {
            messageResId=R.string.incorrect_toast;
    }

        Log.v(TAG, Boolean.toString(mIsCheater));

    Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();
    }
```

The horizontal issue was due to me having a landscape layout and not having the cheat button declared in the xml.